# Why doesn't Ivanti Pulse-secure allow me to see my internal network?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, windows-11

When I activate `Ivanti Pulse-secure` to connect my `Windows 11` PC to the corporate VPN network, I am blocked from accessing computers on my private network.

I have all my computers configured with 2 IP addresses:

- DHCP (router network 192.168.1.xxx/24)
- static: 192.168.0.yyy/26

On the main PC, after Pulse starts VPN connection, I see my routing changed as:

```
192.168.0.64    255.255.255.192         On-link     10.26.230.153      1
192.168.0.xxx   255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.xxx    281
192.168.1.0     255.255.255.0           On-link     10.26.230.153      1
192.168.1.yyy   255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.xxx    281
```

But, to see the other computers, I need the following routing:

```
192.168.0.64   255.255.255.192         On-link     192.168.0.xxx    281
192.168.0.xxx  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.xxx    281
192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0           On-link     192.168.0.xxx    281
192.168.1.yyy  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.xxx    281
```

I need at least the 192.168.0.64 network routing to remain unchanged (with the route above indicated).

What can I do?

Comment: Have you asked your IT?

Comment: @Toto,  I work from home and they answer me that is a problem of mine!

Comment: @SJB - I assume we’re talking about a VPN. The reason your unable to see devices on your intranet is an intentional decision of the configuration of the VPN connection by your Administrators. There is no solution to your problem as a user without the ability to make the necessary configuration changes

Comment: Ask IT to enable split tunnel on the Pulse Secure VPN client.

Comment: Go back to your IT department and ask them if/how/why/not *split tunnelling* is enabled on their system.

Comment: @Ramhound, under Linux I found the solution to delete the route 192.168.0.64 and then insert it with the route I want, but under windows I'm not sure I know how to handle it.